# Extend PatternLayout for custom Header in log4j2

Tags: log4j2

I need too overwrite the "getHeader()" function from the PatternLayout of Log4j2.
The header is not just a static string so i cant just use the "header" properties in the configuration. I have to call a function during runtime to get status informations and add them to the header.

I already tried some example of extending the PatternLayout without success. Even the examples in the official log4j documentations don't work.
On Logback it was much easier to extend the "getHeader()" function and it was working fine.

I tried it with a lookup and the header property in Patternlayout as well which is working in general but it will never refresh the value on rolling files.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it now with a lookup:
log4j2.yml:

```
PatternLayout:
      Pattern: "%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}{UTC}; %msg; %level; %logger; %class; %method; %thread; [%file:%line]%n"
      Header: $${headerlookup:header}
```

Lookup Plugin:

```
@Plugin(name = "headerlookup", category = StrLookup.CATEGORY )
public class IONLog4j2HeaderLookup extends AbstractLookup {

/**
 * Lookup the value for the key using the data in the LogEvent.
 * @param event The current LogEvent.
 * @param key  the key to be looked up, may be null
 * @return The value associated with the key.
 */
@Override
public String lookup(final LogEvent event, final String key) {
    return new IONLogLayout().getFileHeader();
}
```

}

Don't forget "$$" to read the value on runtime.